# Storing information inside LMS, SCORM

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I was reading this pdf 'SCORM users guide for programmers' which i downloaded from ADL website, and I get to know that we can only store some specific set of information in LMS; like learners name, score etc.

I was wondering can I make an SCO which could store my OWN set of information inside LMS. Like suppose if I was making an assessment SCO how would I store the answers which the learner give to each question, and later fetch it from LMS somehow? Is it possible anyhow? storing my own information inside LMS?

Kind Regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SCORM doesn't currently have a mechanism that allows for extensions to store specific new data elements.

It does however provide you with storage buckets that you can use to store your own data in a textual format for later retrieval. This will allow you to store and retrieve data, but it will not generally be understood by the LMS. cmi.suspend data is the most commonly used field for this purpose. In SCORM 2004 4th Edition, there is also a bigger and more robust adl.data structure.

If you want to report learners' responses to questions, there is a set of SCORM data model elements for that. Look at the cmi.interactions collection in the [SCORM Run-Time Reference Chart](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/).

If you really do need to start storing more expressive data than what SCORM currently allows, you should look at the upcoming next generation of SCORM, the [Tin Can API](http://scorm.com/tincan/). That's not widely deploy yet, but you will start to see early implementations in the next couple months.